# MutableLiveData switchMap never called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to update my list with **MutableLiveData** and **switchMap()** the problem that even if I post new value to the **LiveData** **switchMap()** never called.

Here is how i update **MutableLiveData** from my :

```
 viewModel.getProductListingById(queryModelId)
```

**getProductListingById()** implementation in **viewModel**:

```
fun getProductListingById(newQueryModelId: ProductListingQueryModelId) {
        queryModelId.postValue(newQueryModelId)
    }
```

Here is how i define **queryModelId**:

```
    private val queryModelId = MutableLiveData<ProductListingQueryModelId>()
```

Finally here is **switchMap()**:

```
val productListingId = queryModelId.switchMap { query ->
        //This log statement never called
        Log.e("ProductViewModel ","id =${query.id}")
        productListingRepo.getProductListingById(query.id.toInt(), query.body).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

Comment: Is `newQueryModelId` an entirely new object? Or is it the same object that was already saved in the `MutableLiveData`, but with different properties? In other words, try constructing a brand new `ProductListingQueryModelId`, initializing it with all the correct properties, and then pass it into `getProductListingById()`.

Comment: yes it is a new object

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the problem you have to make sure that u observe your **LiveData**
in your ui so in my case **val productListingId** never observed in my ui after adding observers to it every thing work as expected.